# ASUS motherboard drivers install all of them or the latest one

Tags: drivers

i want to update my asus drivers, but they have 7 bios updates for my motherboard...do I need to install all 7 or just the latest one?

https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/X99-A-II/HelpDesk_Download/

Comment: It doesn't matter, either way is the same, you upgrade your firmware to the current firmware version.  Of course if everything is working you should consider it upgrading

Comment: Unless stated otherwise I think it's safe to assume all updates are cumulative which means the latest one contains all fixes that were featured in previous versions.

Comment: Sometimes you have to install intermediate versions before the latest. Read the instructions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, firmware updates always write the whole firmware to your bios, not doing anything incremental. So you only have to install the latest one, and can skip the version inbetween.

Comment: Sometimes you have to install intermediate versions before the latest. So this answer is not correct.

Comment: As pointed out, while this is correct for most of time there may be a minimum required version for some updates so we can't say always.